# GroupBy работает не корректно в IQueryable

Tags: c#, group-by

Работаю с Entity Framework. Есть класс

```
   class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }
}
```

Получаю данные из БД c использованием GroupBy:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

В БД есть такие данные :

```
IsMain = true, Name = "entity"  
IsMain = false, Name = "entity"
IsMain = true, Name = "Entity"
```

После я делаю так:

```
 foreach (var entity in grouppedEntitiesByName)
        {
            var mainEntity = entity.Single(a => a.IsMain);
        }
```

Здесь получаю ошибку Sequence contains more than one matching element. Дело в том что GroupBy дает три элемента, кажется он не различает маленькие и большие буква. 
После я использовал ToList:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().ToList().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

Всё работает. Но почему это не работает с IQueryable. Есть ли какое то решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Все верно, EF устроен так, что по умолчанию все строки сравниваются без учета регистра, в том числе `Contains`, `GroupBy` и прочие

Comment: Видимо, надо изменить параметры сортировки столбца на серверной стороне, как советуют здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843382/6766879

Comment: проблема не в ef а в sql, который в принципе сравнивает без учета регистра, хотя возможно это также может зависеть от базы данных.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232690/sql-case-sensitive-group-by

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать **FirstOrDefault** вместо **Single**, так:

```
var mainEntity = entity.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsMain);
if(mainEntity != null)
{ ... }
```

Single: выбирает единственный элемент коллекции, если коллекция содердит больше или меньше одного элемента, то генерируется исключение

Comment: Это не подходит. Как вы видите на БД есть только один entity у которого IsMain==true.

Comment: @DIlshod бд возвращает два значения, без учета регистра, поэтому подходит

Comment: Такое решение разрушает мою логику. **В БД есть много entity с одинаковым именим,  только только ц одного из них IsMain==true**. Например есть дасять entity с именим 'MyEntity', но только у одного из них  IsMain==true